# How to append array object in FormData using axios, nuxt, vue js?

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I have data collection using array object, how can i append data using From data ? in Axios, Nuxt, Vue js

```
let collection = [{
        name: "tony",
        obj: {
          id: 1,
          code: "obj1",
          name: "john",
        },
        arr: [{
          id: 1,
          code: "arr1",
          name: "john"
        },{
          id: 2,
          code: "arr2",
          name: "john",
        }],
        address: "USA"
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

FormData represent only name and value. Basically Key: value structure. So you may need to stringify this object to send this value as string.
Ex `key: JSON.stringify(collection);`

Comment: but in my data i have a file image to send with FromData, if i convert to JSON.stringfy(collection);

how can i sent it ?

Comment: No Image will not be sent as data. You will need seperate key to send file. But remember formdata will only take key and value. value can be string or file.

Comment: can you explain to me how i write the code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with append. e.g:

```
collection[0].append("valueName", actualValue)
```

Comment: this the manulay to append the data

actualy i have a lot data, and i must looping the array object and image file, this is the problem, if i want loop the data what must i do ?

Comment: @Richard i didn't fully understand the case, can you give me an example?
You want to append some data in nested arrays or something else?

Comment: i want POST the data and the data have array object when i loop the data form data can't read and return [object Object]